# Python: Class method that references today's date, unless class is __init__ with something else

Tags: python

I am probably overengineering this - but I was hoping some can help me understand why this isn't working.  My goal was to build a class that primarily uses classmethods, except in the case where a user creates an instance of the class so that they can change the assumed internal date.

```
import datetime as dt

class Example():
    """ 
    Primary usage is via classmethods, however if historical is needed then create 
    an instance of the class and pass reference date    
        
    """
   
    @staticmethod
    def _get_time_to_mat():                
        return dt.date.today()        
    
    def __init__(self, ref_date):
        self.ref_date = ref_date
        
        #change the date the class method uses for **this instance** 
        def _override_get_time_to_mat():            
            return self.ref_date        

        # I was hoping that I could overwrite the function with a new function object
        self._get_time_to_mat = _override_get_time_to_mat        
    
    @classmethod
    def get_date(cls):
        return cls._get_time_to_mat()
```

However, when I run it

```
example_instance = Example(dt.date(2021,6,1))

print(Example.get_date())
print(example_instance.get_date())
2022-08-28  
2022-08-28  # I would expect this to be 2021-06-01 !
```

Any help is appreciated!  Thanks

PS.

1. I'd like to avoid having to pass a ref_date to the classmethod as an optional argument.
2. I'd also like to avoid just using an instance of the class where the ref_date is passed with a default of dt.date.today().

Comment: You aren't changing the class attribute; you're creating a new instance attribute that is shadowed by the class attribute. (See https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2015/02/09/understanding-python-metaclasses/#object-attribute-lookup for the gory details on how attribute lookup works on instances of a class.)

Comment: Hmm, got you.  Any suggestions on how to implement something like this?  I’m open to suggestions

Comment: My first suggestion would be to *not* expect `get_date` to be primarily used as a class method. Just require an instance with `ref_date` defaulting to `None`; then `get_date` can decide whether to call `dt.date.today()` or return the actual attribute value.

Comment: IIRC, class methods were initially added as the analog of C++ static methods. It was later realized that they were different and `staticmethod` was added for that use case. Class methods themselves were recognized after the fact as the "correct" way to add alternative constructors to a class, which is what they are primarily used for.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would implement the behaviour that you want.

```
class Example():
    ref_date = dt.date.today()
    
    def __init__(self, ref_date=None):
        if ref_date:
            self.ref_date = ref_date
```

```
>>> Example.ref_date
datetime.date(2022, 11, 28)
>>> example_instance = Example(dt.date(2021,6,1))
>>> example_instance.ref_date
datetime.date(2021, 6, 1)
```

Have a class attribute with the default value of the reference date, which gets overwritten if the user instantiates an object with another value. Then get rid of the getter method (it's fine in Python, it's got [properties](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property)).

Comment: Thanks for this - I guess what I wasnt sure about this approach was when the dt.date.today() would actually execute.  Ie, every time the classmethod is called?  Or just when the overall program is loaded.  I'm worried about the case of the program being "live" for a few days, does the default ref_date become wrong

Comment: dt.date.today() is execute when the file where the class is writen is readed by your program..

Comment: Good question. In my case the `today()` method will execute once when the program is loaded (I think). If you want an attribute to implement some functionality you should definitely turn it into a property, though I have no experience on turning class attributes into properties. Anyway I guess that's the way to go if you want the reference date to be updated every time it is called.

Comment: Got it - sounds like I am definitely over-engineering it.   I'm mostly trying to make intellisense cleaner with classmethods...

Comment: Oh - I just noticed you were calling the ref_date directly in your output. I still need to call the classmethod though ...

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest that to implement this you use class attributes instead of overriding a class method in the initializer.

The following code should work

```
class Example():
    """ 
    Primary usage is via classmethods, however if historical is needed then create 
    an instance of the class and pass reference date    
        
    """
    ref_date = dt.date.today()          
    
    def __init__(self, ref_date=None):
        self.ref_date = ref_date
        if ref_date:
            self._override_class_date(ref_date)
        
        #change the date the class method uses for **this instance** 
    @classmethod
    def _override_class_date(cls, date):            
        cls.ref_date = date
    
    @classmethod
    def get_date(cls):
        return cls.ref_date
```

In the following code the _date is a class atribute, in the case you create an instance, with a new date you override the class attribute with the instance attribute. Note if you assign self.ref_date to the new value in init you will only override the instance value that shadows the class attribute

Comment: Thanks Lucas.  Giving this a try now

Comment: I think my only thought is that you might have an issue if you default ref_date to None and set it to self.ref_date in the first line.  As in that case you might break the class functionality if an instance is created but user doesn't pass  a ref_date in

Comment: I dont think your method works, as it affects all future cls.ref_date calls

Comment: mmmm then I have not understood what was your question. You want to access get_date from the class and not from the instance? if you have a classmethod this will always refer to the the class not to the instance. If want you want is either have access to the class or the instance, you should not work with the classmethod decorator.

Comment: Yeah, i think thats the right answer... that a class decorator isn't the way to go